# What does the term "throttle" mean when an object "throttles" a method

Tags: java, blackberry-jde

More specifically, I am looking the BlackBerry 6.0 API Animator class whose constructor describes that it "Creates an Animator object that throttles update() calls at the specified frame rate." http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/animation/Animator.html

Does this just mean that the object triggers the update method at the specified frame rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, that means that the object *limits* the `update()` calls to that specific frame rate.

Please see Google's first [definition](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3athrottle).